# How to randomly copy the contents of a text document to my clipboard

Tags: python-3.x

### This is my original question

The following script copies the text in `/home/my_files/document1.txt` to my clipboard.

```
import pyperclip
path = '/home/my_files/document1.txt'
The_text_of_the_file_that_will_be_copied = open(path, 'r').read()
pyperclip.copy(The_text_of_the_file_that_will_be_copied)
```

Let's say `/home/my_files/` contains the following five documents:

- `/home/my_files/document1.txt`
- `/home/my_files/document2.txt`
- `/home/my_files/document3.txt`
- `/home/my_files/image1.jpg`
- `/home/my_files/image2.png`

I would like to create a script to randomly copy the contents of one of the three text documents in `/home/my_files/` to my clipboard.

Of course the following script does **not** work but it shows some of the modules I've been experimenting with.

```
import glob,random,pyperclip
pattern = "*.txt"
path = random.choice((glob.glob(pattern))("/home/my_files/"))
The_text_of_the_file_that_will_be_copied = open(path, 'r').read()
pyperclip.copy(The_text_of_the_file_that_will_be_copied)
```

Do you have any relevant suggestions for me?

### I added the subsequent content to my original question above

When I tried the following solution which @Jacob Lee created...

```
import glob
import random
import pyperclip

files = [os.path.abspath(f) for f in glob.glob("./home/my_files")]
path = random.choice(files)
with open(path) as f:
    pyperclip.copy(f.read())
```

I received the following error message...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "abc.py", line 3, in <module>
    path = random.choice(glob.glob(pattern))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/random.py", line 290, in choice
    raise IndexError('Cannot choose from an empty sequence') from None
IndexError: Cannot choose from an empty sequence
```

Someone else suggested the following script to me...

```
import glob,random,pyperclip
pattern = "/home/my_files/*.txt"
path = random.choice(glob.glob(pattern))
print("copying contents of ", path)
The_text_of_the_file_that_will_be_copied = open(path, 'r').read()
pyperclip.copy(The_text_of_the_file_that_will_be_copied)
```

But that script doesn't work either. I received the following error when I ran that script...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "abc.py", line 3, in <module>
    path = random.choice(glob.glob(pattern))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/random.py", line 290, in choice
    raise IndexError('Cannot choose from an empty sequence') from None
IndexError: Cannot choose from an empty sequence
```

I am confused.

Comment: Looks good. By "suggestions" are you asking for someone to write the code for you?

Comment: `pattern = "/home/my_files/*.txt"` if you use this pattern and you have the directory structure you mentioned in the question, there is no way for this to not work. It definitely needs to be working. Are you sure you have those files? Try `cd /home/my_files` and run `ls`. I think you don't have those files there.

Comment: @Asocia Thanks for explaining that to me. I removed my solution from my question. Also, I tried to answer my own question but StackOverflow requires that I wait 6 hours to accept my own answer. I will accept my own answer after 6 hours from now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The following successfully copies the entire contents of a random text file in /home/my_files/ to my clipboard

```
import glob,random,pyperclip
pattern = "/home/my_files/*.txt"
path = random.choice(glob.glob(pattern))
print("copying contents of ", path)
The_text_of_the_file_that_will_be_copied = open(path, 'r').read()
pyperclip.copy(The_text_of_the_file_that_will_be_copied)
```

### Thanks to @Asocia

Thanks to @Asocia for insisting that the script above works correctly. I don't know what I had been doing wrong, but I must have been doing something wrong when I indicated the script above did not work properly.

Answer (score 0):

You're code raises a `TypeError: 'list' object is not callable` exception when you try to assign `path`, in this line:

`path = random.choice((glob.glob(pattern))("/home/my_files"))`

`glob.glob()` returns a list (possibly empty). (Also, you put the `glob.glob()` call inside redundant parentheses.) Then, you try to call `glob.glob()("/home/my_files/")` (in essence, `[...]()`, raising the `TypeError` exception.

```py
import glob
import random
import pyperclip

files = [os.path.abspath(f) for f in glob.glob("./home/my_files/*.txt")]
path = random.choice(files)
with open(path) as f:
    pyperclip.copy(f.read())
```

Comment: I am sorry that my response is poorly formatted. I am struggling to figure out how to format comments on StackOverflow. When I ran your code, I received the following error... Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "abc.py", line 8, in <module>
    path = random.choice(files)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/random.py", line 290, in choice
    raise IndexError('Cannot choose from an empty sequence') from None
IndexError: Cannot choose from an empty sequence

Comment: Comments cannot be formatted. Append the new information to your original question, and/or edit as required.